# How can I add the variable every loop?

Tags: java, loops

So I want to add the variable `rolltotal` with itself every time it loops.

```
    Random ran = new Random();
    int roll;
    int rolltotal;
    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    roll=s.nextInt();
    while(roll!=-1) {
        int die1 = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
        int die2 = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
        int die3 = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
        int die4 = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
        int die5 = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
        int die6 = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
        rolltotal=die1+die2+die3+die4+die5+die6;
        System.out.println(rolltotal);
        int a;
        a=rolltotal+rolltotal;
        System.out.println(a);
        roll=s.nextInt();
    }
```

I have no idea how to explain it, I hope you understand what I mean. So lets say I got 20 and after the loop I got 18. How can I add those two numbers.

Comment: change  `rolltotal=die1+die2+die3+die4+die5+die6;` to  `rolltotal+=die1+die2+die3+die4+die5+die6;` and your done

Comment: Except for initializing the variable when you declare it, otherwise you can't add to the "current" value because it won't have one.

Comment: That was really it! Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of `rolltotal` reference outsuide the loop and get a temporary sum vairable inside the loop at the eo of loop update the  `rolltotal=rolltotal+tempSum`

```
Random ran = new Random();
    int roll;
    int rolltotal;
    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    roll=s.nextInt();
    while(roll!=-1) {
        int die1 = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
        int die2 = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
        int die3 = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
        int die4 = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
        int die5 = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
        int die6 = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
        int tempSum=die1+die2+die3+die4+die5+die6;
        System.out.println(tempSum);
        rolltotal=rolltotal+tempSum;
        System.out.println(rolltotal);
        roll=s.nextInt();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code quite a bit, simulating rolling six die does not require that you track six independent variables (unless you want to display them). You could use an `IntStream` with a limit instead. Also, the more idiomatic Java way to write a loop that terminates on comparison and assignment is something like,

```
Random ran = new Random();
int rolltotal = 0;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int roll;
while ((roll = s.nextInt()) != -1) {
    int round = IntStream.generate(() -> ran.nextInt(6) + 1).limit(6).sum();
    System.out.println(round);
    rolltotal += round;
}
System.out.println(rolltotal);
```

Note that the above does not actually use `roll` for anything (but I included that to demonstrate how you can, if you need to). It could be simplified even further. Like,

```
Random ran = new Random();
int rolltotal = 0;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
while (s.nextInt() != -1) {
    int round = IntStream.generate(() -> ran.nextInt(6) + 1).limit(6).sum();
    System.out.println(round);
    rolltotal += round;
}
System.out.println(rolltotal);
```